# Run Specific Test Classes Ant Deployment Tool

Tags: apex, unit-test, ant

I am using ANT deployment tool on Salesforce to run specific test classes. For an example, my build.xml looks like below.

```
<target name="deployCode">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" 
           sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
           deployroot="codepkg" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests">
        <runTest>TEST_AccountController</runTest>
    </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

My package.xml Looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>AccountController</members>
        <members>TEST_AccountController</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

But in my classes folder, there are some other Apex classes that are not specified in package.xml

My problem is, for those classes, I get the error `Error: Not in package.xml`

If I put  `<members>*</members>` in package.xml then it run all the test classes other than the one that I specified in the build.xml

How can I run only specific test classes while there are many other Apex classes in the classes folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something you can do in Ant directly. You would need to build a temp folder, copy the files you need to this folder, and deploy that instead. This was a limitation of the older metadata api (mdapi for short). Use [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_install_cli.htm) if you want this type of flexibility:

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/classes/AccountController.cls -l RunSpecifiedTests -r TEST_AccountController -w 10
```

Answer (score 2):

The classes in classes folder and in package.xml should be an exact match. Else deployment will fail. The deployment parameters like which test classes to run can be specified in ant build file like.

```
<target name="deployCode">
    <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" 
           sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}"
           deployroot="codepkg" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests">
        <runTest>TestClass1</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass2</runTest>
        <runTest>TestClass3</runTest>
    </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm?search_text=test

Comment: Thanks, In my actual scenario, the source folder is a GIT repo. That's why I want to run test / deploy specific classes while there are some other classes in the folder. So, seems its not possible.

Comment: manually create package.xml based on git commit files?

Comment: You can see the manually created package.xml (specifying only the classes I need) file in my question. Then I get "Not in package.xml" error for the other classes in the folder

Answer (score 0):

In the ANT deployment folder.. keep only those classes which u want to deploy and in buid.xml file add those test classes which u want to run. like below i have

```
<target name="deployCodeCheckOnly">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="retrieveUnpackaged" checkOnly="true" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests">
    <runTest>ContactTrigger_Test</runTest>
  </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

Comment: In my actual scenario, the source folder is a GIT repo. That's why I want to run test for specific classes only, while there are some other apex classes in the folder.

Comment: in tht case..u can create a new branch .. run specific test classes for specific classes...then when successful u can merge those changes to main branch